# Aws Kinesis consume message reactive

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-kinesis, reactor, spring-reactor

I am trying to implement a kinesis consumer reactive. My current understanding is that a kinesis shard is always consumed by a thread so the thread consuming it will subscribe.

Here is my code:

```
   private static CompletableFuture<Void> responseHandlerBuilderReactor(KinesisAsyncClient client, SubscribeToShardRequest request) {

        SubscribeToShardResponseHandler responseHandler = SubscribeToShardResponseHandler
                .builder()
                .onError(t -> System.err.println("Error during stream - " + t.getMessage()))
                .onEventStream(p -> Flux.from(p)
                        .ofType(SubscribeToShardEvent.class)
                        .flatMapIterable(SubscribeToShardEvent::records)
                        .limitRate(2)
                        .buffer(2)
                        .subscribe(e -> {
                            // decoder.decode(record.data()).toString();
                            e.forEach(el-> {
                                try {
                                    System.out.println(decoder.decode(el.data().asByteBuffer()));
                                } catch (CharacterCodingException e1) {
                                    e1.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            });
                        }))
                        .build();
        return client.subscribeToShard(request, responseHandler);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        KinesisAsyncClient client = KinesisAsyncClient.create();

        SubscribeToShardRequest request = SubscribeToShardRequest.builder()
                .consumerARN(CONSUMER_ARN)
                .shardId("shardId-000000000000")
                .startingPosition(StartingPosition.builder().type(ShardIteratorType.TRIM_HORIZON).build())
                .build();

        responseHandlerBuilderReactor(client, request).join();

        client.close();
    }
```

I think there are many details I don't understand about kinesis and even if I keep reading it is not becoming more clear.

The documentation says that this connection will have a low-latency HTTP/2 connection but I have no idea how to handle this between runs, what I mean if I restart the app I don't want to process already consumed messages. How can I implement a RecordProcessorCheckpointer for the reactive version?

Also after a few minutes, the process exits without any error. I remember reading in the documentation that I need to resubscribe. Is it enought if I run in infinite loop: `responseHandlerBuilderReactor(client, request).join();`?

Comment: Did you get any solution on this ? I am also looking for Kinesis reactive consumer . There is one good library for Scala I found that uses KCL https://github.com/WW-Digital/reactive-kinesis